# PMD with grails project

Tags: grails, pmd

Does PMD works with grails project, i.e. with .groovy files??

i'm using STS editor,

if it works, what setup i have to do?

Please let me know, if anyone have any idea

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any specific reason to use STS editor...? checkout this if you have a choice to select the best IDE for grails/groovy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233664/best-ide-for-grails-groovy

Comment: Lot of people have started using STS, and eventually diverted to netbeans/eclipse etc... Personally I would recommend to use netbeans just because of its rich support for groovy/grails...

Comment: well, STS will be the best IDE for groovy n grails,

Comment: You will get PMD integrated with all these editors : JDeveloper, Eclipse, JEdit, JBuilder, BlueJ, CodeGuide, NetBeans/Sun Java Studio Enterprise/Creator, IntelliJ IDEA, TextPad, Maven, Ant, Gel, JCreator, and Emacs.

Comment: yes, but PMD will only work with .java files not with .groovy files, I'm able to integrate PMD with STS its working fine for .java files in STS but not working for .groovy files

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of any PMD plugin for Groovy/Grails. However, there is a [CodeNarc Grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/codenarc), which does similar kinds of static analysis on Groovy/Grails code.

Comment: Yep, CodeNarc is a good/the best choice for analysis of Groovy code!

Answer (score 2):

codeNarc is one of the best choices for grails projects, thou it is ignoring java classes that potentially are part of your project.

I have not seen any pmd or findBugs plugins for grails that would take care of the java portion. You can use the STS/Eclipse PMD plugin thou to analyze explicitly the src/java/ folder.

Unfortunately the findBugs eclipse-plugin is not able to limit to a certain parts of the project so it no big use (findBugs works purely on class files and works through the complete project).

I guess it should be possible to write a grails pmd plugin that would analyze the java parts of a grails project.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Grails 3, the build system uses Gradle. There is a PMD gradle plugin which you could use to perform static analysis on your java source files. There is also a Codenarc gradle plugin which you can use to perform analysis on the groovy files in your project.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html